# drop down width-fix that is calculated via JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am fixing a drop down width issue that is coming via js.
Drop down menu(child ul) width is shortened by some px. I am unable to find the existing js code so i count the ul width and did addition on it by some pixels.
**Problem is in ie browser inline width is coming in em and in Firefox it is coming in px. that's why width are not same in both browsers.**
Here is my code:

```
<script>
j$("#container .sf-menu").each(function () {
            j$(".menu-list").each(function () {
                j$i = j$(this).width();
                j$(this).width(j$i + 6)
            });
        });
</script>
```

When i removed my js code, by default its inline width is coming in em.
Please let me know how can i make the width size in em in all browsers.

```
<div id="container">
           <ul class="sf-menu sf-js-enabled sf-shadow">
           <li class="selected"><a href="#" id="ctl02_ChapterButtonGroupLoopedlbtn1" onclick="return false;" class="sf-with-ul" style="padding-right: 4.5em;">Looping</a>
           <ul class="menu-list" style="float: none;">
           <li style="white-space: normal; float: left; width: 100%;">
           <input type="submit" class="FormButton loop" id="ctl02_8b81504d-2351-430d-9b68-eba2e0e6bd38" value="chap1" name="ctl02$8b81504d-2351-430d-9b68-eba2e0e6bd38" >
           </li>
           </ul>
           </li>
           </ul>
           </div>


<style>
#container {
    position: relative;
}
.sf-menu li ul {
    background: url("/a/images/drop-bg.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #D8D8D8;
    border: 1px solid #B0B0B0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.sf-menu ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: -999em;
    width: 10em;
}
.sf-menu, .sf-menu * {
    font: 11px Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.sf-menu li li {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: medium none;
    text-align: left;
}
.sf-menu ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.chapter-title .sf-menu li {
    right: 0;
}
.chapter-title li.selected, .chapter-title li.selected:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}
.chapter-title li.selected .sf-with-ul, .chapter-title li.selected .sf-with-ul {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.chapter-title li.selected .sf-with-ul, .chapter-title li.selected .sf-with-ul {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.chapter-title li.selected a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.chapter-title .sf-menu a {
    padding-left: 5px;
    top: -2px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Where is the html for .menu-list? And can you include any css for those elements you are using?

Comment: @spacebean...i have add the related css..i have add ".menu-list" class via js, thats why it was not in HTML code..now u can check

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded to make the width in "px" in all browsers but in IE-7 width is not same as other browsers.
 In all browers with is coming via js as "283px" but in IE-7 it is "271px". I am not able to find out whats wrong with the code:

```
<script>
j$("#container").find("#ctl02_ChapterButtonGroupLoopedlbtn1").next("ul").addClass("menu-list");
        j$("#container .sf-menu").each(function () {
            j$(".menu-list").each(function () {
                j$i = j$(this).width();
                j$(this).width(j$i + 6 + "px")
            });
        }); 
</script>
```